# Insert formulas into cells based on the value of an independent cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a large sheet (Sheet1) with multiple values that are normally manually filled.

If I populate some of the cells based on an independent cell (Order nr) this would save time and also keep the sheet dynamic.

I've written the formulas to extract the data from a different sheet (Sheet2), but I don't want to populate all the cells in Sheet1 with the formulas I've created as that would disturb Sheet1. This is because not all rows have an order nr.

Is it possible to write code that would insert these formulas in the cells based on whether there is a value in the "order nr" row/column?

Example:
If there is a value in cell L1, it would insert formulas to B1, C1, F1 and G1? Each of the formulas are different as they are pulling data from different columns in sheet2.

The formula I'm using:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(FILTER(SHEET2!B:B;SHEET1!C1=SHEET2!A:A));"";FILTER(SHEET2!B:B;SHEET1!C1=SHEET2!A:A))
```

In other words: Is there a code that would input whole formulas in to specific cells based on the cell value of a different cell?

Comment: Sure, you can use a loop and `Not IsEmpty` to test whether the cell in the order nr column is populated.

Comment: Where you able to read my last edit? Is this done in VBA or just as a formula in the cell?

Comment: `Not IsEmpty` is VBA,  yes.

Comment: So how would I write this in VBA? Considering the formula has to change according to the cell that has value (example: cell C5 has a order nr, the formula would need to change to SHEET1!C5 for both places in the formula. Not sure if the formula is the best one to use either.

Comment: You would use a loop: `For i = 1 to ...`, then concatenate `i` into the formula: `"=IF(ISBLANK(FILTER(SHEET2!B:B;SHEET1!C" & i & "=SHEET2!A:A));"";FILTER(SHEET2!B:B;SHEET1!C" & i & "=SHEET2!A:A))`.